# Owl Carousel responsive not working only desktop?

Tags: php, wordpress, owl-carousel

hi guys on my site https://www.woohwho.com/services/b2b-accountancy-ltd/ my owl carousel is working for a desktop but for some reason on mobile it ignores it and just puts all items in one slide and i'm not sure why,

he is the owl carousel code i'm using:

```
$('#owl-one').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop:true,
            margin:5,
            nav:true,
            navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide'></div>"],
            autoPlay: true,
            responsiveClass: true,
            responsive:{
              0:{
                  items:1
              },
              600:{
                  items:1
              },
              1000:{
                  items:1
              }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On inspecting your page and CSS, it says you have added the following CSS style on the `.owl-item` class:

```
@media (max-width: 768px)
.owl-item {
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

Removing/disabling this style solves the issue. Any reason for adding this style? If this was for some other page, make sure to add styles by `.page-id-9 .owl-item` for example for a specific page with id 9.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i have now noticed the slider goes off the screen now a little bit?

Comment: No its fine, do not resize window. If you do resize (to check responsive) then refresh the page in that window size because owl carousel generates item sizes dynamically on load.